# How do I call a javascript function from Go/WASM using Invoke that acts upon a js.Value?

Tags: go, webassembly

I need to check for fullscreen support with my Go WASM Canvas project, before switching to fullscreen mode.  I have the following code so far:

```
var fullscreenFunc         js.Value
var fullscreenNotSupported bool
```

set with the following logic:

```
fullscreenFunc = app.Get("requestFullscreen")
if fullscreenFunc.IsUndefined() {
    fullscreenFunc = app.Get("mozRequestFullScreen")
    if fullscreenFunc.IsUndefined() {
        fullscreenFunc = app.Get("webkitRequestFullscreen")
        if fullscreenFunc.IsUndefined() {
            fullscreenFunc = app.Get("msRequestFullscreen")
            if fullscreenFunc.IsUndefined() {
                fullscreenNotSupported = true
                println("Fullscreen not supported")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to call the correct function with js.Invoke, but I see no way to tell the Invoke upon which object the call should be made.  My 'app' value is being interpreted just as a param.

```
func Fullscreen(app js.Value) {
    if fullscreenNotSupported {
        return
    }
    fullscreenFunc.Invoke(app)
}
```

resulting in:

```
panic: JavaScript error: 'mozRequestFullScreen' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
```

So am I correct in my thinking that the only way I can call the correct method, is not to store the Function, but to store a string of the function name, and then 'invoke' / 'call' it using the following approach?

```
app.Call(fullscreenFunctionNameString)
```

It feels like I misunderstood the purpose of Invoke.  Is it only for js.Global() type calls?

[edit] Using 'Call', at least it seems possible to derive the function name without having to repeat the above browser specifics:

```
fullscreenFunctionName = fullscreenFunc.Get("name").String()
app.Call(fullscreenFunctionNameString)
```

It doesn't answer the question, but is probably of help to someone trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to invoke get turned into arguments for the javascript function it wraps. Since those fullscreen functions don't need any arguments, I think you might just need to change:

```
fullscreenFunc.Invoke(app)
```

To:

```
fullscreenFunc.Invoke()
```

...assuming `app` is the same JS element in both places. If not your `Call` solution is probably your best bet.

Comment: The problem is that the fullscreen call needs to act upon an 'Element' object ('app' in my case).  I have gone with the Call syntax, but will leave this open for now.